# Ouput of grep with new line

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk, text-parsing

I am working on a script which parses information within open xml documents and parses the output from a script to provide a csv output.

I am stuck on the last hurdle.

```
find /media/path/to/files -type f -iname '*.xlsx' -exec perl parseXML.py {} \; \
    | grep -v 'Document\ name\|creator\|lastModified\|Printed\|created\|modified' \
    | tr '\n' '.'; echo \n \
    >> list.csv
```

The issue with this output is that I end up with one massive list for all documents and sorting that out in python or perl appears above my knowledge level.

I was hoping there is a way to avoid this occurring from the offset by using sed

```
(find /media/E01880-0-CH5-W001/Working/E01880-4-CH5-E001/ED/ -type f -iname '*.xlsx' -exec perl parseXML.py {} \; | grep 'Document\ name\|creator\|lastModified\|Printed\|created\|modified' | tr '\n' '.'; echo \)n >> list.csv
```

Alas to no avail, this just removes the line containing the modified information.

Finally this evening I tried to alter the output using sed and some regular expressions

```
cat PleaseWork.csv | sed  -i 's/modified[^"\r\n]*\./&\\n/g' >> NewFile.csv
```

Where the syntax in theory should replace modified and any characters up until a period with the matched expression and a new line but I received a sed error no input files and i think I have stared enough at the screen for now.

Please help.

I am using the snortdlp code off of google:

http://snortdlp.googlecode.com/svn-history/r115/trunk/src/python/read_open_xml.pl

Comment: cat PleaseWork.csv | sed 's/modified[^"\r\n]*\./&\n/g' >> NewFile.csv

Comment: exec **perl** parseXML **.py**? Is that a perl script with a python extension?

Comment: @TLP It will work fine as long as parseXML.py has a shebang line. :-(

Comment: Re: "I received a sed error no input files": That's because you used the `-i` flag, which tells (some versions of) `sed` that you want it to modify an existing file. For example, `sed -i s/a/b/g foo.txt` will actually overwrite the file `foo.txt` with a modified version of itself, with all `a`-s replaced by `b`-s. In your case, you *don't* want `sed` to do that; you want to pass in text on standard-input, and have the result come out on standard-output. So, you can just remove the `-i` flag.

Comment: @TLP No, perl will execute python for you in that case.

Comment: @TLP See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html (search for "bizarre").

Comment: @melpomene I learn something every day on StackOverflow.com :)

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question correctly, you are trying to output the entire line (but not the newline) for all files that match 'Document name', 'creator', etc., and print the entire line (and a newline) for lines matching 'modified'.  Just skip the grep and use awk instead:

```
awk '/Document name|creator/{printf "%s.", $0} /modified/'
```

(I've shortened the match for clarity--add the other tags as needed.)

Comment: The `printf` will mess up badly if the input contains any number of `printf` formatting characters. This would be better: `printf "%s.", $0`